# Probability of set intersection in case of combination with repetitions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

So, I'm creating a database engine and I'm trying to describe my benchmarks with some maths, but probability and combinatorics defeated me, hence this question.

The total number of possible $k$-element combinations with repetitions chosen from a set of $n$ elements is:
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k}$$

In my use case, I have the n elements pre-generated. Then I select $k$ numbers from an uniform random $U(0,N)$ distribution. This is my combination with repetitions.

What is the probability of the event when two random $k$-element combinations ($k$-element sets) intersect?

Bonus questions:

What is the probability of the event when two random $k$-element combinations intersect, and there are exactly $x$ intersecting elements?

What is the probability of the event when two random $k$-element combinations intersect, and there are more/less than $x$ intersecting elements?

Comment: Back up a bit.  You talk about $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ different $k$-element combinations with repetitions.  Okay, fine.  You then talk about "*two random $k$-element combinations*" and asking if they intersect.  To be perfectly clear... you are talking about some programming application and realworld probability scenario here it seems... How are you randomly picking these?  The vast majority of methods to randomly select such a $k$-element combination with repetition will *not* have these $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ options be equally likely.

Comment: In my use case, I have the $n$ elements pre-generated. Then I select $k$ numbers from an uniform random $U(0,N)$ distribution. This is my combination with repetitions.

Comment: As for actually attempting to tackle your problem... this seems highly tedious and difficult... As an idea to an approach, pick the intersection first.  For each way in which the intersection could be arranged, pick a subset of $n$-elements for which the "first" of the combinations will have all appearing for the non-intersecting members.  For each of these... distribute the remaining elements of the second set among the unused.  This seems like it will devolve into "*case-hell*" and you would be better off using a computer to calculate or better yet, just to approximate.

Comment: Yeah, it looks tedious indeed. I tried to tackle it for a while, hence this question. Thank you anyway!

Comment: "*I select $k$ numbers from a uniform random distribution*" That is precisely what I was talking about... that manner of selection will not have the $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ outcomes be equally likely to occur.  Take for simple small example $n=k=2$... flipping two coins.  There are three possibilities... flipping 0 heads 2 tails, flipping 1 head and 1 tail, or flipping 2 heads and 0 tails.  The probability of two tails however is $\frac{1}{4}$... not $\frac{1}{3}$.  Similarly, 1 head 1 tail is $\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: ...Rather... the $n^k$ different *ordered* outcomes are what are equally likely.  If you choose to unorder them after the fact, that is your choice... but it doesn't suddenly make them equally likely after the change.  The unordered outcomes will have probability proportional to the number of different ordered outcomes which correspond to it.

Comment: Hmm, I see. You are right, my method of generating these combinations is not uniform. This definitely makes it much more complicated...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you say "there are $x$ intersecting elements," are you counting repeats? For example, suppose the first multiset is $\{4,5,5,6\}$, and the second set is $\{4,5,5,7\}$. Would the number of intersecting elements be $2$ or $3$?

Comment: In my case, it would be 2. However, I am more interested in any intersection - the number of intersecting elements would be just a nice bonus for my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my answer to reflect a useful comment, selected a more appropriate combinatoric approach, and tested it computationally, so it is almost certainly correct now.

We will solve this problem from a combinatoric perspective. The way you generate sets, according to your comment is identical to sampling a string of length $k$ where the alphabet is of size $n$.

Your question hence becomes the probability of generating two strings, $s_1$ and $s_2$ that do not share a single character. We shall compute the number of such pairs given $n$ and $k$, then divide by the total number of pairings.

First let us assume that $s_1$ is composed of $x$ unique characters. Then $s_2$ can only select its characters from the remaining $n-x$ characters, and there are $(n-x)^k$ ways to accomplish this.

What remains is to count how many $s_1$ we have if we are forced to use exactly $x$ unique characters. This is a classic IEP application, and I give the following formula:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^x {(-1)^j \times {x\choose j} \times (x-j)^k} $$

This needs to be multiplied by all methods of selecting $x$ unique characters of $n$ to use, which is $n\choose x$.

We finally combine to obtain
$$\sum_{i=0}^k { n \choose i} \times (\sum_{j=0}^i {(-1)^j \times {i\choose j} \times (i-j)^k}) \times (n-i)^k   $$

To get the probability of non-intersection, simply divide by all possibly string pairings, which is $n^{2k}$.

Computation is possible in $O(n^2)$, and perhaps $O(n)$ by individually tabulating sub-parts of this equation  as to avoid repeated sub-problems.

A final note: You are dealing with multisets, so for what you care, permutations of the string are the same. But your method of generating strings means that permutability influences frequency of strings, and thus must be considered in probabilistic analysis. Ex, the multiset ${1,1,1,1}$ is far rarer than ${1,2,3,4}$ since the latter can be generated using $4!$ ways according to your method. That's why I work with strings.

Comment: This is wrong for a number of reasons.  First, you've only explored the case of no intersection between the sets at all and not what was actually asked of there being an intersection of a particular size.  Next, when talking about there having been $i$ unique elements in the first set... you used $(i/n)^k$ which does not actually correspond to all $i$ of those elements having actually appeared at least once... merely *some* subset of those $i$ elements as having appeared but not necessarily all.

Comment: Fixed. And I couldn't solve the bonus parts. @JMoravitz